# Differential Equation Basic - please explain the detail of this step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking through a solution of some problem. It has this step I don't quite understand. Please help me clarify.

Relevant equations:

- $ u(x) = y^3 $
- $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3y^2} \frac{du}{dx} $

Problem:

$$(1)\quad x^3 \frac{du}{dx} + 3x^2 u(x) = 6x $$

$$(2)\quad\quad \frac{d}{dx} (x^3 u(x)) = 6x $$
How do you get from [1] to [2]. Is think its not the first time I've seen something like this, is it a special property or pattern?

Comment: It's the familiar Product Rule for differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

That is the product rule at work; if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ then

$$(f g)' = f' g + f g'$$

In your case, $f(x) = u(x)$ and $g(x) = x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via this way similarly: $$x^3u'(x)+3x^2u(x)=6x$$ If you know the [**Differential of a function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) , you will see that the LHS of above OE has a form $$d\left(x^3u(x)\right)$$ Now you need just to solve $$d\left(x^3u(x)\right)=6x$$ by a simple integration of both sides.

Comment: @amWhy: I saw how you edited. I'll try to do it for my other answers here. Thank you very much.

Comment: there's so much to learn about formatting; I'm always learning new tricks. I just copied your link, highlighted the terms "Differential of a function", clicked on the "chain-link" at the top left menu, and pasted the link into the pop-up asking for the URL. You can also do this `[Differential of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function)` and only the expression "Differential of a function" will show up - (blue, as a link)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [integrating factor trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). In your case, the integrating factor is simply one, so $$x^3(u(x))'+u(x)(x^3)'=(x^3\cdot u(x))'.$$ Remember that $$(f(x)\cdot g(x))'=f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x).$$